# How to remove desktop interface and run gui application from the command line?

Tags: command-line, gui, desktop-environments

I have tried to remove desktop interface on my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) PC and replace initial screen (desktop & application launcher) with the command line interface and launch guy application from command line. I got some errors messages and gui application not Launched when I removed it.  Is there any solution to do this?.

Comment: It’s hard to solve errors without their error messages, so please [edit] and provide them.

Comment: It's common to see GUI app error messages when called from the command line. They happen when called from desktop too you just don't see them.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? We only support Ubuntu here. Sorry.